# Problem Installing pylidar in anaconda

Tags: python, lidar

I am trying to install pylidar. i tried the following codes.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels rios
conda create -n myenv pylidar
conda activate myenv
```

As i found out they moved the library from rios to armstonj i tried

```
conda config --add channels armstonj
```

but it keeps failing to solve the environment

I also tried

```
conda install -c armstonj pylidar
```

But still the same problem

[image]

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pylidar -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.6

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting to make it easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

`pylidar` (v.0.3.5) in armstonj channel is published for Linux OS only.

`pylidar` (v.0.4.4/0.4.0) in rios channel is published for Windows, Linux and macOS.

For an updated and multiplatform installation use:

```
conda install -c rios pylidar
```

Comment: Gave me a new error. i have tired python version 3.6 and 3.9 but its still the same error